# android-support-v7-appcompat/res/styles_base.xml

Tags: android, xml

I have imported android support-v7 appcompat library From File >Import >Android >Existing Android Code Into Workspace >sdk >extra >android >support >v7 >appcompat. when I click finish I get " android supprt v 7 appcompat" in project explorer, it shows me an error.

in android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values\styles_base.xml -> I get the following error:
"error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

I have search this problem couldn't solve my problem.

**I wanted to upload screen shoot unfortunately, I am not able to since it needs at least  10 reputation :(**

any ideas please

Comment: @Pankaj Kuma if you know please help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are not compiling with the Android 5.0 (API level 21) SDK.

You need to install API 21 via the SDK manager, then update your project settings to compile with API 21.

Comment: I have installed API 21 through sdk manager, sorry how to compile with API 21, I am new to android :(

Comment: It sounds like you are using Eclipse, so right click your project, click "properties," then select "Android." There you can change your project build target to Android 5.0.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question the error I am getting is from " android-support-v7-appcompat" whenever I add a support library

Comment: I have right clicked on support library and clicked on properties> selected android> and selected API 21, BUT no changes